# Rails 4 - how to generate statistics through "joins" and "includes" commands in Activerecord?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord

I kind of stuck at trying to generate statistics for my application. The relevant part of the application has the following structure:

```
class CarRegistration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ride
  belongs_to :car
  ...
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_registration
  ...
end

class Ride < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :passenger
  belongs_to :driver
  has_many :car_registration
  ...
end

class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
  ...
end

class Passenger < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
  ...
end
```

I am trying to get a list of rides, top drivers and and top passengers. I originally tried something like this:

```
@rides_finished = Ride.joins(:car_registration)
                      .select('rides.id')
                      .where("(car_registrations.ride_id = rides.id)                                    
                              AND rides.status = 3
                              AND rides.driver_currency = ? 
                              AND rides.passenger_currency = ?", currency, currency)
                      .distinct # against displaying one shipment multiple times
```

And then I tried:

```
@top_pasengers = @rides_finished.joins(:passenger)
                                .select('passengers.id, passengers.name, count(rides.passenger_id) AS count_all')
                                .where('rides.passenger_id IS NOT NULL')
                                .group('passengers.id')
                                .order('count_all DESC')
                                .limit(10)
```

But when I run these queries, I get

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'count_all' in 'order clause': ...
```

Any help how to get the needed numbers?

Thank you very much

Comment: Is it possible that CarRegistration → `has_many` → Ride? It's a `belongs_to` in the question, but would make more sense to me the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing because your query uses `Ride` but there is no `Ride` in the model definitions listed. I've focussed purely on the example queries you listed.

I think it would be easier to start with a single query chain for 'top passengers':

```
Passenger
  .select('passengers.*')
  .select('count(1) as ride_count')
  .joins(:rides)
  .where(rides: { status: 3,
                  driver_currency: currency,
                  passenger_currency: currency })
  .group('passengers.id')
  .order('ride_count desc')
  .limit(10)
```

That will get you an ActiveRecord::Relation of `Passenger` models that also respond to a `ride_count` call, e.g. you could use it like:

```
results.each do |p|
  puts "#{p.name}: #{p.ride_count}'
end
```

If all that works, you should be able to adjust the query to get the top drivers.

To get the list of finished rides, I suggest a separate, simple query:

```
Ride.where(status: 3,
           driver_currency: currency,
           passenger_currency: currency)
```

Let me know if any of that produces an error.

Comment: Hi @Lucas, thank you for your answer. I am sorry for the missing part, when I was writing the post, part of it got deleted while updating it. Now it's complete.

Comment: Because I need to use on the statistics page information about the finished rides, I load them into `@rides_finished`. And then I hoped that once I have the rides loaded (and saved in a variable), I can extract from there another information - like information about passengers & drivers.

Comment: That can work for small data sets, but I generally encourage the use of queries on the database to avoid loading 'too much' into memory in the Rails app. I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: I believe this schema is complicated, but I am not sure if I can come up with a better one... As the use of the application grows, so it grows also the amount of data in database tables (we use MySQL).